# Определение времени распознавания объекта на видео нейронной сетью

Tags: python, tensorflow, видео

При работе с нейронной сетью столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно определить время детектирования объекта на видео. Т.е. в выводе должно писаться на какой секунде (минуте) появился распознанный объект. Пока получается только распознавать и считать объекты.
Использую нейронную сеть https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10

Answer (score 1):

Ну, нужно определить время детектирования. Что вы сами сделали для решения проблемы? Ну, кроме того, что взяли чужую готовую нейросеть и ее запустили? Покажите, что именно у вас не получается, в чем возникли проблемы.  На этом форуме принято вот так.  И тогда вам с удовольствием помогут. А вопросов "вот чужой код, что в него надо вставить, что-бы он решал мою задачу" тут не любят.

Но поскольку вы новичек, а новичков тут стараются не обижать, подскажу, что для измерения времени выполнения любого фрагмента программного кода в Python можно использовать модули `time, timeit, datetime`, а также встроенные типы данных и методы в модулях numpy и pandas. Выбирайте, что вы лучше знаете  -  и вперед. Удачи.